# Only Notify Animation listeners on Specific values

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-animation

I have a problem where an `Animation` that should only be updated on integer numbers *fires* way too often.

```
update() { // gets called for 0, 0.01, 0.02, .., 1.0, .. but should only get called on 0, 1, ...
  final integer = animation.value.toInt();
  renderHeavyAnimation(integer);
}
```

In this case `update` should only be called when `animation.value` reaches the next integer number. Saving the previous number and then only rendering once a new integer is reached did not work *for me* because [`CustomPaint` takes a `Listenable`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter/CustomPainter.html), which is the `animation`, and the painter will clear the canvas on overy update of the `Listenable`.

I also tried to make use of [`IntTween`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/animation/IntTween-class.html).

```
animation = IntTween(begin: ...).animate(animationController);
```

However, this `animation` will just notify multiple times for the same integer values, which is exactly what I had before.

#### Summary

I am searching for a way to only notify the listeners of an animation when *either* the value changes (using an `IntTween`) or better only for specific values.

Comment: simply pass `ValueNotifier` to your `CustomPainter` and use `Timer.periodic` / `Stream.periodic` to animate it

Comment: @pskink This might help in some cases. However, the way I am corrently working around this problem is by just using a `ValueListenable` in combination with an `Animation` because animations give me more control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listenables do not implement filtering events. Not that this is not possible, but would lead to reimplementing `Stream`.

Take this as an opportunity to convert your `CustomPaint` into a `RenderBox` instead. `CustomPaint` is basically a simplified `RenderBox`, as such the latter allows you to do the same things but more optimized to your use-case.

---

Your final implementation will depend on how you use `CustomPaint` though.

For example, if you don't use `child`, you may want to make a `LeafRenderObjectWidget` while if you do, you'll want a `SingleChildRenderObjectWidget`.

Comment: Mind sharing a simple implementation of what `CustomPaint` does using `RenderBox`?

Comment: Edited. It's pretty difficult to give a generic implementation. There are many things that `CustomPaint` do that you may not need.